вылетает instance pm2 во время ошибки
pm2 версия 5.3.1, запущено приложение в режиме кластера, 7 instance
Периодически после ошибки:
Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:87:16)

вылетают друг за другом 2-3, а то и все instance
pm2 App name: id: disconnected exited with code 0

После такой ошибки вылеты происходят не всегда чаще ошибка просто появляется в консоли и полностью:
Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:87:16) {
  errno: 'EPIPE',
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}

При этом вылета нет и ошибка попадает в обработчик https.on('clientError', () => ...);
Нагрузка на сервер не большая, была гораздо больше и без вылетов. Но надо отметить такое резко начинается в середине дня и резко заканчивается в конце.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что может быть, куда копать ?
